# Unable to connect remote server in c# and object reference not set to an instance of object while sending sms on mobile

Tags: c#

I am trying to send sms from c# windows application on mobile users. while 
using this code the following error shows:

> 1) Unable to connect remote server
>
> 2) Object reference is not set to an instance object

```
try{
        String result;
        string userName = "abc@gmail.com";
        string hash = "hashkey";
        string numbers = "911234567890"; // in a comma seperated list
        string message = "This is your message";
        string sendermo = "TXTLCL";

        String url = "http://api.textlocal.in/send/?username=" + userName + "&hash=" + hash + "&numbers=" + numbers + "&message=" + message + "&sender=" + sendermo;
        //refer to parameters to complete correct url string

        StreamWriter myWriter = null;
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(url);
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        try
        {
            myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
            myWriter.Write(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse objResponse = HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close();
        }
             MessageBox.Show(" "+result);
        }
            catch (Exception ec)
        {
        MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is unclear to you in error message "Unable to connect remote server"? It is not the code issue, but rather something wrong with your network connection. I suspect second error is derived from the first one.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for quick response. Actually i am not able to connect to server and send sms to given mob. no \even having good net speed, actually i wanted to send mobile sms from c# application. Kindly assist in this or you have any other way to do that using 3rd party API..

Comment: Have you tried to visit this url via web browser?

Comment: Thanks rogalski, i tried and found this JSON values {"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}

Comment: looks like invalid credentials

Comment: Solved.. thanks for the quick responses.. it was credential problem and provided mob no is DND activated..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask